# Display Pressure coefficient for multiple points at across the span line of an airfoil in fluent

Tags: ansys, cfd, fluent, airfoils

Learning to use ANSYS Fluent as part of my computational engineering course I have previously modelled a 2D wing and been abled to XY plot for the pressure coefficient against x coordinate.

my struggle is when within a 3D case, how do you plot pressure coefficient against at various points across the span line?

the wing is an Onera M6 wing.

[image]

where i want to plot 6 separate XY plots of C_p against X/m at each solid line, moving up the dotted span line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Anyone that may come across this post, the answer is: to create an iso surface using the wall as the 'from surface' and setting it to Mesh -> Z-coordinate and entering the desired value of Z.

this creates a surface along the span line, of which you select when you plot XY chart of C_p against X.

repeat the surface creation for as many points across the span as you desire